# what purpose the random code generated in url structure?

Tags: url

why directory based websites have random code on url. why they do it like this?
Eg- https://start.cortera.com/company/research/k6s5ous6l/b--b/
Here, the code is generated randomized for each url?

/k6s5ous6l/

Comment: *Here, the code is generated randomized for each url?* Mostly - yes. This code is unique random code generated for the (session-folder) pair.